# preg_replace regular expression outputs nothing

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
    $str = '<div class="hello">{author}</div><div id="post_{id}"><div class="content">{content}</div></div>';
    $pattern = '/\{([a-z _0-9]+)\}/i';
    $subst= array('author'=>'Mr.Google','id'=>'1239124587123','content'=>'This is some simple text');
    $str = preg_replace($pattern,$subst['$1'],$str);
    echo $str;
```

Every instance of `{text}` turns out to be "" is there something I am doing wrong with the capture group? I did this with `preg_match_all` and it returns as `{author}` and `author` is this the issue being lead here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such case, you need **[preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)**:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) use ($subst) {
    return $subst[$matches[1]];
}, $str);
```

Another solution is using **[strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)** function:

```
// $subst needs to be changed a bit.
$subst= array('{author}'=>'Mr.Google','{id}'=>'1239124587123','{content}'=>'This is some simple text');
echo strtr($str, $subst);
```

Comment: @EasyBB Anonymous functions need php version >= 5.3, check it.

Comment: PHP version 5.2.* GRR

Comment: Just reading the PHP docs and this says = `(PHP 4 >= 4.0.5, PHP 5)` and the count parameter was added 5.1.0

Comment: @EasyBB: That’s the version notice on `preg_replace_callback` – it was first introduced with 4.0.5, and included in PHP 5 from the beginning; anonymous functions however were introduced with 5.3. But as I said in my answer, you don’t _need_ an anonymous function here, you can still pass a callback function to `preg_replace_callback` the old-fashioned way, it’s just a little “uglier”. And why do you mention the `count` parameter, is that relevant here for what you are trying to do?

Comment: No I just stated this because of the version 5 :D

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `preg_match_all` is evaluated *before* the function runs. (Like all parameters always are.)

Enable proper error_reporting, and PHP will tell you: *Notice:  Undefined index: $1 in […]*

You can not do it this way, because `$1` will only reference what is captured, when the function has already found the matches – you will need to use `preg_replace_callback` instead:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern,
    function($matches) use ($subst) {
        return $subst[$matches[1]];
    },
    $str
);
```

Edit: In case you can’t use anonymous functions, this should work for PHP < 5.3.0 :

```
$str = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'my_custom_replacement_function', $str);

function my_custom_replacement_function($matches) {
    global $subst;
    return $subst[$matches[1]];
}
```

Comment: I can't use use preg_replace_callback since my version of php is 5.2.* I am use 000webhost since it is free and I'm trying to learn as much as I can before the fall semester starts for college.

Comment: You are drawing the wrong conclusions here … `preg_replace_callback` is available since 4.0.5 already, only anonymous functions are only available since 5.3.0 – but it does not have to be an anonymous function, see examples for `preg_replace_callback` in the manual. (But xdazz makes a good point, maybe `strtr` is even more suitable for what you want to achieve.)

Comment: `strtr` did work except I can't change my `subst` specifically as these are for my returned array from a mySQL query. So should I try the preg_replace_callback in different matters. and can you explain what a PHP anonymous function is? Also thank you for clarifying this for me~

Comment: Okay, see my edit for an example how to use `preg_replace_callback` without an anonymous function, but the “old-fashioned” way by passing the name of the callback function as a string.

Comment: (And on a side note, if your primary goal is learning, but your web host prevents you from learning what is “state-of-the-art” and forces you to use an outdated PHP version (the latest 5.2 is from December 2009!) – then it might be preferable to just install a web server with a current PHP version on your local machine …)

Comment: I've never use WAMPP or XAMPP so I'm going to wait on that -.-